# How do I invoke SHGetImageList properly? Is it possible to retrieve HIMAGELIST with it?

Tags: delphi, winapi, imagelist

I was trying to examine shell's shared image list, followed seemingly straightforward (but actually not very clear) [PSDK documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185) including **the remark what I'm free to cast between `HIMAGELIST` and `IImageList` types** (the first thing I found suspicious later). So, I wrote the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  IID_IImageList: TGUID = '{46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950}';
  IID_IImageList2: TGUID = '{192B9D83-50FC-457B-90A0-2B82A8B5DAE1}';
var
  himl: HIMAGELIST;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);

  OleCheck(SHGetImageList(SHIL_LARGE, IID_IImageList, Pointer(himl)));
  ImageList1.Handle := himl;
end;
```

But it work very poorly: API call returns `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)` and then crashes with multiple access violations, suggesting some binary incoherence between application and library. However, the stock Delphi import of function I've used looks correct:

```
function SHGetImageList(iImageList: Integer; const riid: TGUID; 
  var ppvObj: Pointer): HResult;
function SHGetImageList; external shell32 name 'SHGetImageList' delayed;
```

The second this I found confusing in documentation is what `riid` parameter description list only one possible value - `IID_IImageList`which might not match my intention to retrieve a handle type.

So, how do I invoke SHGetImageList properly? 
And is it possible to retrieve `HIMAGELIST` with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with Delphi's stock declaration in the `ShellAPI` unit. It is missing the `stdcall` calling convention.  To work around that, you can declare the function manually in your own code:

```
function SHGetImageList(iImageList: Integer; const riid: TGUID;
  var ppvObj: Pointer): HResult; stdcall; external shell32;

procedure TTestForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  IID_IImageList: TGUID = '{46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950}';
var
  himl: HIMAGELIST;
begin
  //CoInitialize(nil);
  OleCheck(SHGetImageList(SHIL_LARGE, IID_IImageList, Pointer(himl)));
  ImageList1.Handle := himl;
end;
```

Note: VCL applications already call `CoInitialize` if you don't remove the `Application.Initialize` call in the project source.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I've overlooked this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> So, how do I invoke SHGetImageList properly?

The function output is an interface, so you need to declare an interface variable:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  iml: IImageList;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  OleCheck(SHGetImageList(SHIL_LARGE, IImageList, Pointer(iml)));
end;
```

> And is it possible to retrieve HIMAGELIST with it?

Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185.aspx):

> The IImageList pointer type, such as that returned in the ppv parameter, can be cast as an HIMAGELIST as needed; for example, for use in a list view. Conversely, an HIMAGELIST can be cast as a pointer to an IImageList.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  iml: IImageList;
begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  OleCheck(SHGetImageList(SHIL_LARGE, IImageList, Pointer(iml)));
  ImageList1.Handle := HIMAGELIST(iml); // or HIMAGELIST(Pointer(iml));
end;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)` and then the number non-continuable exceptions.

Comment: The cast can be made at the call site. Declaration in 'shellapi' is wrong.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz If the cast is made at the call site then the refcount of the returned interface will not be managed correctly. The function returns an interface that must be released. And technically, Delphi's declaration is not wrong.

Comment: It surely should be `stdcall`. Or is yours already.. I checked with XE2.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. I checked 10.0 Seattle and it is still not `stdcall`.  I don't have 10.1 Berlin to check.

Comment: @Remy - If the cast is made at the call site, will there still be an interface returned with the function?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: The `stdcall` has been missing since `SHGetImageList()` was first added to the `ShellAPI` unit in D2010. I have filed a [bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15117) with Embarcadero. And yes, the function will still return a refcounted interface, the function has no concept of how the caller treats it.